# Extract specifc string in javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having this string `http://xyz.pair.com/to.html?#data3`

I want to extract the data (3) after "#data". I am using this method :

```
window.onload=function(){
    var prmstr = window.location.search.replace("#data", "");
}
```

But getting blank string.

Thanks

Comment: the url you posted is a link to get the string or it's the string itself?

Comment: Try with : window.location.hash

Comment: didn't think it could be the string itself: try `window.location.href.split('#data')[1]`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this:

`'http://xyz.pair.com/to.html?#data3'.split('#data')[1]`

or

`location.hash.split('#data')[1]` //better

result : `3`

Comment: The downvote is not mine, but uses of `split()` such as `location.hash.split('#data')[1]` are less efficient than simple calls to [substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr).

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want `window.location.hash` and not `window.location.search`